# R: Dynamically define range of values based on other dataframe

Tags: r

I have two dataframes, one (`df1`) with samples organised by `group` and `time`:

```
|sample |group | time|
|:------|:-----|----:|
|Oct    |B     |   10|
|Feb    |A     |   15|
|Nov    |A     |    7|
|May    |A     |    5|
|Jun    |A     |    0|
|Mar    |C     |   12|
```

The other one (`df2`) that defines for each `group` a `stage` defined by a start (`beg`) and end (`end`) time:

```
|group |stage | beg| end|
|:-----|:-----|---:|---:|
|A     |I     |   4|   8|
|A     |II    |   9|  12|
|A     |III   |  13|  20|
|B     |I     |   3|  12|
|B     |II    |  13|  18|
|B     |III   |  19|  21|
|C     |I     |   2|   6|
|C     |II    |   7|  12|
|C     |III   |  13|  17|
```

What I want is to add to `df1` the `stage` from `df2`,  based on the values of `group` and `time`.

Desired output:

```
|sample |group | time|stage|
|:------|:-----|----:|----:|
|Oct    |B     |   10|    I|
|Feb    |A     |   15|  III|
|Nov    |A     |    7|    I|
|May    |A     |    5|    I|
|Jun    |A     |    0|    I|
|Mar    |C     |   12|   II|
```

What I have tried, is to use `mutate` + `case_when()` and  to define dynamically the range of values that
against which I'm testing `time`:

```
df1 <- df1 %>%
  mutate(stage = case_when(time %in% df2[df2$stage=='I'& df2$group==group, 3]:df2[df2$stage=='I'& df2$group==group, 4] ~ 'I',
                           time %in% df2[df2$stage=='II'& df2$group==group, 3]:df2[df2$stage=='II'& df2$group==group, 4] ~ 'II',
                           time %in% df2[df2$stage=='III'& df2$group==group, 3]:df2[df2$stage=='III'& df2$group==group, 4] ~ 'III'))
```

which does not work. Problem being, I suspect, `df2$group==group`.

I guess my strategy is not correct, but I'm stuck here.

Comment: Hi amaizel, welcome to Stack Overflow. If you are intending to use the [table feature](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277716/how-can-i-create-a-table-in-a-post), make sure **not** to surround the table in code block backticks (```). I'm not sure that actually improves the readability though.  Usually it's best to copy the output of the `dput(df1)` command and paste the output into your question (preferred) or paste the tab delimited data from a spreadsheet program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `fuzzyjoin` package :

```
fuzzyjoin::fuzzy_left_join(df1, df2, 
                           by = c('group', 'time' = 'beg', 'time' = 'end'), 
                           match_fun = c(`==`, `>=`, `<=`))
```

Comment: Very nice! I was not aware of this package. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could just loop through your `df1` and find the value in `df2` for which the conditions for group and time are right. If there is only one value (which should be expected if you defined it correctly), get the value.

```
df1$stage=NA
for(i in dim(df1)[1]){
    v = df2$stage[df2$group==df1$group[i] & df2$beg<=df1$time[i] & df$end>=df1$time[i]]
    if(length(v)==1){df1$stage[i]=v}
}
```